# Why is div not floating correctly?

Tags: css

I want to achieve this:
[image: I want to achieve this:]

I am stuck here:
[image: I am stuck here:]

As you can see, the 'Item Description' box is now showing at the right place. I have double-checked the measurements. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="container2">
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/dealstoreconcept-ebay-listing-template2_03.png">
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/dealstoreconcept-ebay-listing-template2_06.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/dealstoreconcept-ebay-listing-template2_07.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/dealstoreconcept-ebay-listing-template2_08.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/dealstoreconcept-ebay-listing-template2_09.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/dealstoreconcept-ebay-listing-template2_10.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/dealstoreconcept-ebay-listing-template2_11.png"></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="images/dealstoreconcept-ebay-listing-template2_12.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="cat">
                <div id="cat-head">
                    Categories
                </div>
                <div id="cat-content">

                </div>
            <div>
            <div id="content-right">
                <div id="des">
                    <div id="des-head">
                        Item Description
                    </div>
                    <div id="des-content">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#container {
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
background-image: url(images/bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center top;
}
#container2 {
width: 970px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
}
#header {
padding-top:14px;
padding-bottom:10px;    
}
#nav {
width:970px;    
}
#nav img {
float: left;    
}
#content {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-right-color: #a81717;
border-left-color: #a81717;
width: 968px;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-bottom: 25px;
padding-left: 8px;
}
#cat {
float: left;
width: 217px;
border: 1px solid #a81717;
}
#cat-head {
width: 209px;
float: left;
background-color: #a81717;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#cat-content {
float: left;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#content-right {
float: left;
margin-left:11px;
width: 721px;
}
#des {
float: left;
width: 719px;
border: 1px solid #a81717;
}
#des-head {
width: 711px;
float: left;
background-color: #a81717;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#des-content {
float: left;
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
width: 689px;
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are missing `</`> a closing tag :/ ?

Comment: If you have some problems like that, use a HTML valdiator. Like W3C :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the background stops displaying at a certain point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is

```
<div id="cat">
                <div id="cat-head">
                    Categories
                </div>
                <div id="cat-content">

                </div>
            <div> ---> not closed div
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/C2pX4/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing tag

CHeck out this fiddle : [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kdj7t/)

Replace

```
<div id="cat">
<div id="cat-head">
Categories
 </div>
<div id="cat-content">
</div>
<div>
```

with

```
<div id="cat">
<div id="cat-head">
Categories
 </div>
<div id="cat-content">
</div>
</div>/*error*/
```